# Singular values of rectangular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, singularity-theory

can any one explain me the need for singular values of a matrix.
Explanation with a practical example will be appreciated

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition

Answer (score 0):

It has multiple applications as in the case of [Applications of Singular Value Decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Applications_of_the_SVD).
The most used ones could be to compute matrix inverse and storing a large but low rank matrix by its "principal components".

If you are into numerical computations, Golub's **Matrix Computations** has a much more detailed explanation.

Comment: Does it has any relation with singularity of matrix in case of a square matrix??

Comment: @sairam Yes it does. Singularity is characterized by existence of one or more zero or extremely small singular values.

Comment: I am very thank full for ur quick reply sir